# asp.net grid dynamic title

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm working with some old webforms code. I want to put an h3 title above the asp:Commandfield button with dynamic content from the grid. (DataField="FacilityName")

Here's my (partial) code for the grid, which works fine.

```
<lfr:SecureDetailsView ID="FirstView" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False"
            DataKeyNames="FacilityID" DataSourceID="FirstView"
            DesiredInsert="false" DesiredUpdate="true" DesiredDelete="false"    
            OnDataBound="FirstView" OnItemUpdating="Facility_ItemUpdating"
            OnItemDeleting="Facility_ItemDeleting" OnItemInserted="Facility_ItemInserted" CommandRowStyle-Wrap="True" FooterStyle-Wrap="True" CellPadding="0" CommandRowStyle-BackColor="White" BorderColor="White">

            <FieldHeaderStyle Width="160px" />
            <Fields>       

                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true"
                    ButtonType="Button" ControlStyle-CssClass="command_button" />

                <lfr:BetterBoundField DataField="MailCode" HeaderText="Store ID" MaxLength="20" 
                    ReadOnly="true" InsertVisible="false" ControlStyle-Width="30%" />
                <lfr:BetterBoundField DataField="FacilityName" HeaderText="Facility Name" MaxLength="128" 
                    ReadOnly="true" ControlStyle-Width="95%" />
```

This is the desired final layout:
[image: Desired Layout]

Easy peasy? Thanks in advance, have a great day!

Comment: So what is your problem? Ind the grid you have BetterBoundField with FaciliryName just move it up before the button. And change font style or check if this control has a wrap property to wrap the data in h3

Comment: @SehaxX I could move it up and apply css, but the betterboundfield has 2 td's, one for the label and one for content.

I could force it that way, but was hoping for a more elegant solution, maybe using asp:label or asp:literal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add an templateField, like:

```
 <Fields> 
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Facility Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <h3><asp:Label ID="someid" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Text='<%# Eval("FacilityName") %>'></asp:Label></h3>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

 <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true"
                    ButtonType="Button" ControlStyle-CssClass="command_button" />
```

EDIT: You should add it after the tag  and before commandField tag. Also not sure about the header I have updated it also for your need.
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried this but it throws an error. Do I have to change something in the code behind? Apologies, beginner alert!

Type 'SecureControls.SecureDetailsView' does not have a public property named 'TemplateField'.

Comment: @ChrisNelson I have updated the answer, please check it.